# how to read a .dat file with delimiter /u0001 and record next record will be separating by next line in spark with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, f#-data

I have .dat extension file which not having any header
1.fields separated by '\u0001'
2.next record will be in new line

how can i read this file in spark with scala and convert to a dataframe.

Comment: i have separate header information of that file to append to create dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, I assume you are using spark  **> 2.x version** -

```
val df = spark
      .read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("delimiter", "\01")
      .csv("<CSV_FILE_PATH_GOES_HERE>")
```